# ReactJS Signup Form Submission FastAPI 422 Unprocessable Entity

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, backend, fastapi

From FastAPI and Sqlalchemy.

```
@router.post("/signup", response_model=ShowUser)
async def create_user(form_data: UserCreate = Depends(), users: Users = Depends(get_user_db)):
    # CHECK IF USER ALREADY EXISTS
    if await users.get_user_by_email(email=form_data.email) is not None:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
            detail="User already exists"
        )
    # CHECK IF USERNAME ALREADY EXISTS
    elif await users.get_user_by_username(username=form_data.username) is not None:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
            detail="Username already exists"
        )

    # CREATE USER WITH USERS METHOD
    # now the hashing of the password is done directly in the creation method
    new_user = await users.create_user(form_data)
    
    # GET TOKEN
    # we no longer create a new uid for JTI, but use the one created automatically during user creation
    # so I modified the get_confirmation_token function so that it takes the user's JTI uid as a parameter
    confirmation_token = Auth.get_confirmation_token(
                            new_user.email,
                            new_user.confirmation)

    # SEND AN EMAIL WITH TOKEN
    try:
        Mailer.send_confirmation_message(
            confirmation_token["token"], form_data.email)
    except ConnectionRefusedError:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
            detail="Email couldn't be send. Please try again."
        )
    # RETURN USER
    return new_user
```

Pydantic MOdels.

```
from typing import Optional
from pydantic import BaseModel, EmailStr
from fastapi import Form

def form_body(cls):
    cls.__signature__ = cls.__signature__.replace(
        parameters=[
            arg.replace(default=Form(...))
            for arg in cls.__signature__.parameters.values()
        ]
    )
    return cls

@form_body
class UserCreate(BaseModel):
    username: str
    email: EmailStr
    password: str

    class Config():
        orm_mode = True

class ShowUser(BaseModel):
    username: str
    email: EmailStr
    is_active: bool

    class Config():
        orm_mode = True
```

React Signup Form Submission.

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from "react";
import axios from 'axios';
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';

import { UserContext } from "../context/UserContext";
import ErrorMessage from "./ErrorMessage";

const Register = () => {
  const [username, setUserName] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState("");
  const [, setToken] = useContext(UserContext);

  
  const submitRegistration = async () => {
    const requestOptions = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
      body: JSON.stringify({ username: username, email: email, password: password }),
    };

    await axios
        .post("/api/signup", requestOptions)
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response);
          alert(response);
          Cookies.set("token", response.data.access_token);
          return response;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error.message);
          alert(error);
        });
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (username.length > 5) {
      submitRegistration();
    } else {
      setErrorMessage(
        "Ensure that the passwords match and greater than 5 characters"
      );
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="column">
      <form className="box" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <h1 className="title has-text-centered">Register</h1>
        <div className="field">
          <label className="label">Username</label>
          <div className="control">
            <input
              type="username"
              placeholder="Enter username"
              value={username}
              onChange={(e) => setUserName(e.target.value)}
              className="input"
              required
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="field">
          <label className="label">Email</label>
          <div className="control">
            <input
              type="email"
              placeholder="Enter email"
              value={email}
              onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
              className="input"
              required
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="field">
          <label className="label">Password</label>
          <div className="control">
            <input
              type="password"
              placeholder="Enter password"
              value={password}
              onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
              className="input"
              required
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <ErrorMessage message={errorMessage} />
        <br />
        <button className="button is-primary" type="submit">
          Register
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Register;
```

Request:

```
XHRPOSThttp://localhost:3000/api/signup
[HTTP/1.1 422 Unprocessable Entity 8ms]

    
body    "{\"username\":\"usertest\",\"email\":\"user@user.com\",\"password\":\"password\"}"
headers {…}
method  "POST"
```

Response:

```
{
    "detail": [
        {
            "loc": [
                "body",
                "username"
            ],
            "msg": "field required",
            "type": "value_error.missing"
        },
        {
            "loc": [
                "body",
                "email"
            ],
            "msg": "field required",
            "type": "value_error.missing"
        },
        {
            "loc": [
                "body",
                "password"
            ],
            "msg": "field required",
            "type": "value_error.missing"
        }
    ]
}
```

From FastAPI backend Error:

```
INFO:     None:0 - "POST /api/signup HTTP/1.1" 422 Unprocessable Entity
```

I'm trying to create a simple signup form Backend FastAPI and serving Frontend in React. I've created the Pydantic Models for the body request but still getting this `422 Unprocessable Entity` error. How can I fix this?

Update: It is working fine in Insomnia client when I hit the `POST` request it gives me the correct data with `200 OK` response.

Thanks for any reply!

Comment: 422 means that it's missing some data that the schema expects. If you expand the `loc` entry in your `console.log` call you'll see exactly which fields weren't found. You should also look at what you're actually submitting to the backend service through the Network pane in your browser's debugging tools so that you're sure you're including the expected information.

Comment: Under Request tab it shows the information I input in the form `{
 "email": "user@user.com",
 "password": "password",
 "username": "usertest"
}`

Comment: The fastapi server log ought to show a traceback for the error.  Please [edit] the question to include it.

Comment: @snakecharmerb `INFO:     None:0 - "POST /api/signup HTTP/1.1" 422 Unprocessable Entity` this is the only log I am getting when i hit the `POST` endpoint.

Comment: @dougj Solved it?